# If loop help needed

Tags: python

I am in a High school coding class and I'm trying to use a def to move a turtle up 20 pixels. I have this working but I am having trouble on one part.

I need to use an if statement to see if they pressed a certain button "3,2,1" and if they don't then it resets them to a starting position

```
import turtle as trtl
rocketship_image = "rocketship.gif"

up = -50

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
wn.addshape(rocketship_image)
wn.bgpic("Screenshot 2020-11-18 at 8.47.14 PM.png")

rocketship = trtl.Turtle()

def start_pos():
  rocketship.pu()
  rocketship.goto(0,-250)

rocketship.right(90)
start_pos()

def draw_rocketship(active_rocketship):
active_rocketship.pu()
active_rocketship.shape(rocketship_image)

def drop_rocketship():
  global up
  rocketship.pu()
  rocketship.clear()
  rocketship.forward(up)
  draw_rocketship(rocketship)


draw_rocketship(rocketship)

if wn.onkeypress(drop_rocketship, "3"):
  drop_rocketship()
```

The if statement is incomplete because I'm stuck on that part. Also, is there any way for it to reset if the input is not "3,2,1"?

Incidentally, the wn.bgpic is a space image.

Comment: when you mean "3,2,1" do you mean they literally type "3,2,1" sequentially on their keyboard? or they type that and hit enter, or they hit any one of those characters? be more specific.

Comment: sequentially, input isn't used :)

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985288/python-turtle-graphics-keyboard-commands

Comment: probably start waiting for the next two when you see that one of them is pressed

Comment: I just need an if statement to sequentially move up a turtle from it's starting position. I don't need to control it, or go any other directions. It's all in a define function and is called each time it loops, and if it's not true then it breaks out and resets from its original starting position

Comment: `if` is not a "loop".

Answer (score 2):

If you're pressing "3", then "2", then "1", in a sequence, you will probably want something like this:

```
...
sequence_321 = 0
if wn.onkeypress(drop_rocketship, <any other key>):
  sequence_321 = 0
if wn.onkeypress(drop_rocketship, "3"):
  sequence_321 = 3
if wn.onkeypress(drop_rocketship, "2") and sequence_321 == 3:
  sequence_321 = 2
if wn.onkeypress(drop_rocketship, "1") and sequence_321 == 2:
  <reset to starting position>
```

This should make it so that when you press "3", let go, press "2", let go, then press "1", it will call whatever the reset function is.  It will also work after you press "3", then "2", then "1", without any of those keys being let go of.
If you're trying to only do this after 3, 2, and 1 are held down in succession, with all three being held down at the end, the logic will be different.  The above code should work for both "3,2,1" being held down at all once and also being pressed one at a time.

Comment: I did this and it worked for just those numbers and that's what I want, although, when I would input the sequence wrong, (123 for example) , it would still move the rocket ship. And I don't want that. I want it to move back if any other key is pressed other than those 3. This includes inputting the code wrong too. Please help. Thank you for this though

Comment: I'm not actually sure about the mechanics of how turtle implements keydown and keyup events.  The reason it moves when you enter the sequence wrong may be because turtle polls the inputs every millisecond; this would mean that as long as the "123" keys are held down at once, it would trigger all of the events since the events are written in order.  You could try writing the 1,2, and 3 keypress events in the reverse order, although I haven't tested this so no guarantees :)  You might also try adding a ```if wn.onkeypress(drop_rocketship, "2") and sequence_321 != 3: sequence_123=0``` in there.

Comment: I hopped into a zoom call with my teacher. We worked on it for an hour and it isn't reading past the if statement. It is saying that because the button is pressed it doesn't need to continue through the statement. It was really bizarre