# Is it possible to take in input through a keyboard button press in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keypress, keyboard-events

I was simply messing around in python with the turtle module, then i thought about making a movement system by change his direction through key presses. I can't find any videos on this this that work on python 3. Is this doable?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985288/python-turtle-graphics-keyboard-commands) then?

Comment: Man thanks just what i was looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle Graphics Keyboard Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985288/python-turtle-graphics-keyboard-commands)